# Can't open folders in Linux nerdtree vim

Tags: linux, vim, nerdtree

I can't open folders in `nerdtree vim`. It won't open the folders, and these funky symbols are being displayed:

[image]

Does anyone have a clue about how to get this working?

I'm running UTF-8.

Comment: Similar question on stack overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8753286/nerd-tree-enter-does-not-open-sub-dirs

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm having a similar problem using Vim 7.2 and the latest NERDtree plugin (4.2.0).

The odd symbols are because your terminal does not support the new arrows. You can fix that by putting

```
let NERDTreeDirArrows=0
```

in your .vimrc

I'm still working on the the more important issue of it not opening directories though.

Comment: ty for the tip,,, let me know if you find a solution to the opening directoryes problem

Comment: Well, not really an answer, but I eventually upgraded to vim 7.3 and the problems seemed to go away.

Comment: Doing as you said, or more specially, adding `let g:NERDTreeDirArrows=0` to my .vimrc, fixed the problem of being able to descend into directories for me.  Here is the original bug report: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/108.

Answer (score 1):

I'm aware this is old, but I had a similar problem and the variable names seem to have changed. The following fixed the problem for me with vim 8.0.427 and NERDTree 5.0.0:

```
let NERDTreeDirArrowExpandable='+'
let NERDTreeDirArrowCollapsible='~'
```

Though may be due to bug in the nerdtree/plugin/NERD_tree.vim script conditional that deals with setting the arrows based on whether it's a windows system or not. Inverting the conditional (Removing the `!`) on line 70 to be:

```
if nerdtree#runningWindows()
```

did the trick as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
let g:NERDTreeDirArrows=0
```

Works for me and it will also fix the open directory issue.